# Hello.js - getting Flickr album and authorising failed

Tags: javascript, flickr, hello.js

I'm currently using Hello.js to establish connection to Flickr and get photo albums from there; however, the response I received through an error object is `"User Not Found"`. I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing here:

```
hello.init( CLIENT_IDS_ALL, {
    scope: "files, photos",
    redirect_uri : "/dashboard",
    oauth_proxy : OAUTH_PROXY_URL
});

function getAlbums(network){
    hello(network).login({
        force:true
    },function(auth){
        hello.api( network+':me/albums', function(r){
            if(!r||r.error) {
                // Caught here: "User Not Found"
                message(list, "Error: " + r.error.message);
                return;
            }
            else if(!r.data||r.data.length===0){
                message(list, "There are no albums in this user's account.");
                return
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I've checked the config for Flickr API and all is good: the key is correct and the app has been enabled for public access. Here are the stats for my app's API calls, apparently no users get authenticated:

```
Number of authenticated users: 0

Total calls in the last hour: 0

Total calls in the last 24 hours: 5
```

What are the possible mistakes have I made here? The same code uses for Facebook authentication and photos retrieving but it works fine, so probably not the code that does that.

Comment: in your code, there's nothing that's flickr specific. Did you expect the code from facebook to work on flickr? Unfortunately, no. Have a look at https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Comment: I think Hello.js does unify the API call, that code works for as many social networks as I specify. I just don't know why for Flickr that error happens, apparently something is wrong with the configuration but I can't seem to find.

Answer (score 0):

I think your initial issue is just that authentication in Flickr requires a secret key, and hello.js leverages an [oauth-proxy](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy) service for that. You can use the default https://auth-server.herokuapp.com to get on with.

Hello.api requests can handle any endpoint and body of data (with varying degrees of success) along with  standardised endpoints listed http://adodson.com/hello.js/#helloapi, its by no means a complete list, there are afterall a plethora to configure, so forgive hello.js for its shortcomings and do like some other developers have done and submit a PR with additions. :)